# How do I solve this second order differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Is there a solution for this equation -

$$y^2\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = k$$

where k = constant

Can it solved assuming, $$y=e^{rx}$$ and then using $$y, y^{'} , y^{''}$$ in above?

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
y^2 \dfrac{\mathrm d^2y}{\mathrm dx^2} &=& k \\
y^2 \dfrac{\mathrm dy'}{\mathrm dx} &=& k \\
y^2 \dfrac{\mathrm dy'}{\mathrm dy} \dfrac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx} &=& k \\
y^2 y' \dfrac{\mathrm dy'}{\mathrm dy} &=& k \\
y' \dfrac{\mathrm dy'}{\mathrm dy} &=& ky^{-2} \\
\displaystyle \int y' \dfrac{\mathrm dy'}{\mathrm dy} \ \mathrm dy &=& \displaystyle \int ky^{-2} \ \mathrm dy \\
\displaystyle \int y' \ \mathrm dy' &=& \displaystyle \int ky^{-2} \ \mathrm dy \\
\displaystyle \frac12 y'^2 &=& -ky^{-1}+C \\
\displaystyle y' &=& \sqrt{-2ky^{-1}+2C} \\
\displaystyle \dfrac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx} &=& \sqrt{-2ky^{-1}+2C} \\
\displaystyle \frac{1}{\sqrt{-2ky^{-1}+2C}} \dfrac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx} &=& 1 \\
\displaystyle \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{-2ky^{-1}+2C}} \ \mathrm dy &=& x+C \\
\end{array}$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Let $y''=uu'$ and solve $uu'=\dfrac{k}{y^2}$. In this case $y$ is independent variable.